# How to fetch unlimited parent and child record from mysql table using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a PHP code like this.According to my code i can get only 3 Levels . How to get unlimited parent & child levels.?

```
$GetNetworkList=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM txuser INNER JOIN txtusernet ON txuser.UserDid=txtusernet.UserDid WHERE txtusernet.Status=0 AND txuser.SponsNo='$DisCode'");
while($FetchNetworkList=mysql_fetch_array($GetNetworkList)){

echo "L1-" . $FetchNetworkList['DistribCode'] ."<br/>";

 $GetNetworkList1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM txuser INNER JOIN txtusernet ON txuser.UserDid=txtusernet.UserDid WHERE txtusernet.Status=0 AND txuser.SponsNo='$FetchNetworkList[DistribCode]'");

    while($FetchNetworkList1=mysql_fetch_array($GetNetworkList1)){

        echo " L2-" . $FetchNetworkList1['DistribCode']."<br/>";

            $GetNetworkList2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM txuser INNER JOIN txtusernet ON txuser.UserDid=txtusernet.UserDid WHERE txtusernet.Status=0 AND txuser.SponsNo='$FetchNetworkList1[DistribCode]'");

                while($FetchNetworkList2=mysql_fetch_array($GetNetworkList2)){   

                    echo "L3-" . $FetchNetworkList2['DistribCode']."<br/>";
                }
    }
}
```

## **OUTPUT**

L1-9400013

L2-9400014

L3-9400015

L2-9400732

L3-9400733

L3-9401377

L1-9400012

L2-9400016

L3-9400155

L1-9400019

Comment: You may need to search for `Recursive Functions` But you have to be careful how to right your code using recursion, because if you do not write it correctly, it may lead to server freezing...

Comment: Actually i don't know how to write Recursive Functions.Are there any other method?

Comment: You either can try to learn how to create a `Recursive Function`(it's really easy) or you can try to use two nested loops. First loop just check a Boolean variable and if it was false exits the loop, the inner loop runs a query and show the records and you pass a variable to it for `txuser.SponsNo` value.

Comment: Many Thanks for your advice .I have written a Recursive Function.Now it's working properly. :)